# Why does type checking not work for what type returns?

Tags: python, typechecking, python-internals

I just tried to test:

```
if type(model_lines) == 'str':
    turn into a list using split
```

based on:

```
In [196]: type('a')
Out[196]: str
```

however, for x, a string:

```
In [193]: if type(x) == 'str':
    print 'string'
   .....:  

In [195]: if type(x) == type('a'):
    print 'string'
   .....:     
string
```

I am curious as to why I cannot use this output to check types, it seems cleaner and faster to read. What does type actually return that won't allow checking by its return display?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because, `type()` returns the class for the object, not the string name of the class , so if you do something like the below, it would work -

```
>>> if type('abcd') == str:
...     print("Blah")
...
Blah
>>> type('abcd')
<class 'str'>
```

As you note above, I checked return of `type('abcd')` against `str` class , not string `'str'` .

If you want the string representation of the class, use `tpye(<something>).__name__` , to get the string name of the class, Though this is not needed for your case, just for your information. Example -

```
>>> type('abcd').__name__
'str'
```

Answer (score -1):

Because `type('a')` can also yield unicode instance. You can assert this by seeing output of `type('a')`.

Comment: I didn't see any difference in ipython shell between type('a') and type('test'). did you mean type(test)? type(test) returns 'function'

Comment: It is my mistake, sorry. just try type('a') .

Comment: This is why it's inadvisable to use `type` to control flow, but it's not why the OP was getting their results. `type('a')` can't evaluate to `<type 'unicode'>`, but `type(u'a')` can as could a string stored in a variable.